# lldb C++ debug for stl container containing dynamic class

Tags: c++, xcode5, lldb

I am writing C++ on Xcode and the only choice is lldb. I define a variable with the type of

```
std::list<State> states;
```

and the **Class** is a self defined class. I tried to use **expr** command and **frame variable**, but they can't help.

The result for **expr** is

> error: Couldn't materialize struct: size of variable states (24) disagrees with the ValueObject's size (0)

and result for **frame variable** is

```
(std::__1::list<State, std::__1::allocator<State> >) states = <variable not available>
```

Comment: Is there a way to view the content of **states** while debugging for lldb? @JasonMolenda

Comment: I did more experiments. If I change the type of states from **std::list<State>** to **std::list<int>**, everything works fine. So lldb don't know my self-define class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable has been optimized away at this point in your program.  The error message from `expr`/`p` is a little unfortunate - there's a change in top of tree which should allow the real error to be emitted - but the behavior is correct.  The `frame variable` output is the correct error message.

You can always do

```
(lldb) image lookup -v -a $pc
```

to see the locations of all visible variables at a point in your program.  They are expressed in the form of a DWARF expression which is usually expressed in terms of the frame base register (`DW_OP_fbreg`) which is usually `rbp` on x86_64 for instance.

If a variable is listed with an empty `location=` field, that means that the variable's value is not available at this pc location.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not familiar with lldb, how could I see the content of states in my example?

Comment: This is not an lldb problem -- no debugger can show you the contents of your variable at this point.  Is your program built with optimization?  Try disabling optimization while you're debugging it.  When the code is optimized, variables can often be eliminated where you would expect them to be available ... or they may be available but the compiler's debug info doesn't describe how to find them.

Comment: I disable the **optimization** of **code generation**, but still not working. **expr** works only after first allocate **states**, but when I firstly **push_back** state, it stops working. Is there any way I can view the content of states? You know, in **Visual Studio**, I could surely see the content of every variables as possible. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your way, but it seems there is no different to set **optimisation** level to none. Is there another way could help? Many thanks.@jason

Comment: You don't need to take my word for it.  Change your build setting to DWARF + dSYM in Xcode, rebuild the project, and next to your `.app` bundle will be a `.app.dSYM` bundle. Run `dwarfdump` on that.  Find the name of your function in the text.  Then find the name of your variable in the text. You will see a list of address ranges in the function, and the location of that variable in each of those ranges.  If you are stopped in one of the ranges where a loc is defined, lldb will show the value. Else, lldb will not. It's all about the debug info from the compiler. It has nothing to do with lldb.

Comment: There is no .app.dSYM, but a file .dSYM appear in my workspace. Since the problem is from LLVM based on your logic, as a result, there is nothing could help then?@jason

Comment: Tracking variable locations, particularly in the case of inlining and optimization, is difficult or many compilers.  Debuggers can only work with what the debug info gives them.  You can often work around these kinds of problems by disabling optimization, or by not forcing functions to be inlined (IIRC functions in a header file are always inlined?  Often inlined?  I don't remember the details of how the choice is made and if it's an impl detail or a compiler detail).  If the debug info doesn't tell the debugger where a var's value is at a given pc, it's a compiler issue.

Comment: I have tried to set the optimisation level to `none` and my function are `not inlined`, still not working. I guess LLVM not work well on the `variables with complex type`. But finally I know it is the problem of LLVM instead of LLDB. Sadly, I have to change my coding style to adapt to the editor now. But thank you very much.@Jason